# Access 2000 - Erase Multiple Forms?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2000

Anyway to Erase multiple forms, queries, etc in Access 2000? (In the designer that is).

Comment: By "erase" do you mean delete the objects or do you mean clearing the data that is displayed in an open form or query?

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer if it helped? I could use the rep.  :)

Answer (score 3):

This worked better for me.  Trying to remove the elements in the loop itself kept having trouble.  I just slapped the object names into an array, then deleted them afterward.

```
Public Sub DeleteAllFormsAndReports()

Dim accobj As AccessObject
Dim X As Integer
Dim iObjCount As Integer
Dim sObjectNames() As String

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete all of the forms and reports?", vbCritical + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    ReDim sObjectNames(0)
    For Each accobj In CurrentProject.AllForms
        ReDim Preserve sObjectNames(UBound(sObjectNames) + 1)
        sObjectNames(UBound(sObjectNames)) = accobj.Name
    Next accobj

    For X = 1 To UBound(sObjectNames)
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acForm, sObjectNames(X)
    Next X

    ReDim sObjectNames(0)
    For Each accobj In CurrentProject.AllReports
        ReDim Preserve sObjectNames(UBound(sObjectNames) + 1)
        sObjectNames(UBound(sObjectNames)) = accobj.Name
    Next accobj

    For X = 1 To UBound(sObjectNames)
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acReport, sObjectNames(X)
    Next X

End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

I create a lot of queries on the fly when a user performs certain actions.  So, I'll create the query, then delete the query once they close the form.  I do this under the On Close event.  It runs regardless of whether the query was created or not.  So, to prevent an error, I tell it to Resume Next.

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "EmployeeDetails"
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "MyEmployeeDetails"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete objects with VBA. Be sure to step backwards when deleting from a collection, for example, this code will delete quite a few objects:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim idx As Long
Dim strName As String

Set db = CurrentDb

    ''Forms
    For idx = CurrentProject.AllForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        strName = CurrentProject.AllForms(idx).Name
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acForm, strName
    Next idx

    ''Reports
    For idx = CurrentProject.AllReports.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        strName = CurrentProject.AllReports(idx).Name
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acReport, strName
    Next idx

    ''Modules
    For idx = CurrentProject.AllModules.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        strName = CurrentProject.AllModules(idx).Name
        If strName <> "Module9" Then
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acModule, strName
        End If
    Next idx

    ''Queries
    For idx = db.QueryDefs.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        strName = db.QueryDefs(idx).Name
        If Left(strName, 4) <> "~sq_" Then
            db.QueryDefs.Delete strName
        Else
            Debug.Print strName
        End If
    Next idx

    ''Relationships
    For idx = db.Relations.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        strName = db.Relations(idx).Name

        If Left(strName, 4) <> "msys" Then
            db.Relations.Delete strName
        Else
            Debug.Print strName
        End If
    Next idx

    ''Tables
    For idx = db.TableDefs.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        strName = db.TableDefs(idx).Name
        If Left(strName, 4) <> "msys" Then
            db.TableDefs.Delete strName
        Else
            Debug.Print strName
        End If
    Next idx
```